# How can I find which NuGet Package is installed on which Class Library project under the same solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution and under this solution I have a few class library projects using dependency injection pattern. I want to find which nuget package is installed on which class library project.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on solution --> Manage Nuget Packages
there you will have a list of installed packages.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But as I said , I want to find which NuGet package is installed on which project. The list of installed package is not helping me because I don't know on which particular project is installed.

Comment: What you wanted to say is to right click a class library project -> manage nuget packages and the list of installed packages for that particular project will be displayed?

Comment: If you right click on the solution itself, you have manage nuget packages for solution.
then you will see list of installed packages, and for each project what version is installed.